# SQL-Find data that appears in one table and not another BUT data appears in more than one column

Tags: sql, sqlite

Literally that is my question. How would one go about querying data that appears in one table and not another, but that data can exist in 2 or more columns?

```
create table Highschooler(ID int, name text, grade int);

create table Likes(ID1 int, ID2 int);
```

In a theoretical social network you're given two tables, one named highschooler, one named
    likes. In likes, id1 likes id2, but it's not 
    necessarily mutual.

Question: Find all students who do not appear in the Likes table (as 
    a student who likes or is liked) and return their names and grades.

I've tried left joins, not in, not exists, is null and am not getting it. I have a feeling there are a few joins in this one but I'm not extremely experienced with SQL.

Using SQlite so I cant use select* in a subquery. Tried that too.

Comment: pick a sql type not mysql or sqlite

Comment: If you give us some sample data, we can do it

Comment: Records don't exist in columns so your question doesn't make sense for a relational databases.

Comment: Drew- Apologies, edited.

Comment: Kbball-Thank you!
Here's the issue:

In a theoretical social network you're given two tables, one named highschooler, one named likes.

Highschooler (id, name, grade)
Likes (id1, id2). id1 likes id2, but it's not necessarily mutual.

Question:
Find all students who do not appear in the Likes table (as a student who likes or is liked) and return their names and grades. 

Much appreciated.

Comment: Put that information into the question. And does this homework not have any example data?

Comment: I have all the data, but no clue how to present it in the question. Would the create table statements suffice?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the anti-join pattern.

```
  SELECT h.*
    FROM highschooler h
    LEFT
    JOIN Likes lo
      ON lo.id1 = h.id
    LEFT
    JOIN Likes lt
      ON lt.id2 = h.id
   WHERE lo.id1 IS NULL
     AND lt.id2 IS NULL
```

That would work on MySQL. I'm not sure about restrictions in sqllite.

That basically says... get me all rows from highschooler, along with matching rows from Likes. Any rows in highschooler that don't have a matching row in Likes will be returned, with NULL values as placeholders for the columns from the Likes table. The "trick" is the predicate in the WHERE clause, that excludes any rows where a match was found.

Comment: I changed the select statement to
    select name, grade
but yes, this was correct in SQLite. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Also found this worked:

```
SELECT name, grade
FROM   Highschooler
WHERE  ID NOT IN (SELECT ID1 FROM Likes) AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID2 FROM Likes)
```

I didn't know that you could separate select statements in the where clause with and/or. I thought they always had to be nested. Evidently you can. I'm new.